# Line Segement Intersection — works sometimes, sometimes not

Tags: javascript, geometry, computational-geometry

I'd like to display the point of intersection of two line segments. The Segments are animated, so they start and stop to intersect, based on progress.

Therefore I have this code:

```
class LineSegment {
  constructor(x1,y1,x2,y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
  }

  contains (x,y) {
    const
      x1 = Math.min(this.x1, this.x2),
      y1 = Math.min(this.y1, this.y2), 
      x2 = Math.max(this.x1, this.x2),
      y2 = Math.max(this.y1, this.y2),
      dot = ((x - x1) * (y2 - y1)) - ((y - y1) * (x2 - x1))
    ;

    return  dot <= Number.EPSILON && 
            x >= x1 && x <= x2 && 
            y >= y1 && y <= y2;
  }
}
```

Somewhere in the code I use that like this:

```
const 
  seg1 = new LineSegment(…),
  seg2 = new LineSegment(…),
  i    = Intersect(seg1, seg2), //working code that calculates x and y values
                                //for the »unbounded« intersection
  contains = i !== null &&
             seg1.contains(i.x, i.y) &&
             seg2.contains(i.x, i.y)
;

if (contains) {
  //show a circle around x and y

} else {
  //remove that one
}
```

In fact, those intersections »flicker«, means they sometimes work and sometimes not. What am I missing here, I guess I am running into numerical issues here?

Due to the comment of @Gilles-Philippe Paillé here to code used to calculate the intersection. I lives in another Helper class and looks like this:

```
intersect ({ a: a2, b: b2, c: c2 }) {
  const 
    {
      a:a1, 
      b:b1, 
      c:c1
    } = this,
    denom = det(a1, a2, b1, b2)
  ;

  //only chuck norris can devide by zero!
  return denom == 0 ?
    null :
    [ -1 * det(b1, c1, b2, c2) / denom,
           det(a1, c1, a2, c2) / denom ];
  }
```

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé The contains method is needed since the point shall only be displayed if both segments contain the point. otherwise it will always be displayed unless the line are linear dependend

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment because I realized that the `dot` was doing a bit more. I get your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dot` variable is in reality the determinant (or the 2D cross product). The problem is that the determinant can be negative. Thus you need to test the absolute value of the determinant. Moreover, `Number.EPSILON` is the smallest non-zero number, which is not useful is case of numerical inaccuracy. You should instead use a more reasonable value:

```
Math.abs(dot) <= 1e-8
```

Moreover, the determinant should be calculated using the segment point, not the bounding box min/max:

```
dot = ((x - this.x1) * (this.y2 - this.y1)) - ((y - this.y1) * (this.x2 - this.x1))
```

Comment: That does not work... Am I wrong with the `dot` calculation??

Comment: @philipp I added a correction. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Since I test with the point of intersection, shouldn't the dot always be zero? The intersection point is on the line? Am I stoned :) Isn't my code the provocation of numerical trouble?

Comment: In theory, yes. It really depends on if you want to keep the `contains` method independant of the `Intersect` method without assuming that the point is on the line. I also added a correction regarding the epsilon value.

Comment: @philipp Great! My pleasure.

Comment: just one last question: doesn't `Math.abs(dot) <= 1e-8` turn the Line into a »Stripe«, even though a very thin one?

Comment: @philipp Exactly. It creates a stripe of width `1e-8*length_of_segment`. It is needed because of numerical inaccuracies. It is the same as when we compare two floating point numbers `a` and `b` using `Math.abs(a-b) < epsilon` to test for equality.

Comment: Thanks… By the way, it should have been: `Number.MIN_VALUE` instead of `Number.EPSILON`. Any reason why 1e-8 was choosen? May that value somehow depend on the actual »extends« of the line segments to process?

Comment: @philipp `MIN_VALUE` is still too small to compensate for numerical errors. `MIN_VALUE` and `EPSILON` are numbers to denote machine precision, i.e., the minimum representable number. However, a series of computations can accumulate errors way beyond machine precision, which is why I always use larger values for these type of computations. `1e-8` is just a value that I found that works well in practice for most circumstances. You can use smaller values if you which, but don't go too small or you will end up with the same flickering problem that you had.

Comment: @philipp In your case, the width depends on the length of the segment, but it should not be a problem. If you are worried that it will affect results, you can choose a smaller comparison value to compensate or normalize the segment vector before computing the determinant (I do not recommend since it is expensive for almost no gain, unless you want to applied it to super precise application).

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to check if one segment ends are on different half-planes in respect to the other segment and vice-versa. This requires no divisions:

```
function side(a, b, p) {
    return (p.x - a.x)*(b.y - a.y) + (p.y - a.y)*(a.x - b.x);
}

function xsect(a0, b0, a1, b1) {
    return (side(a0, b0, a1) * side(a0, b0, b1) < 0 &&
            side(a1, b1, a0) * side(a1, b1, b0) < 0)
}
```

Things are more annoying if you need to include boundary points and/or collinear segments intersection (note also that the intersection point of two segments even with integer coordinates may be impossible to represent exactly with floating point numbers without approximation - e.g. `(0, 0)-(1, 10)` with `(0, 1)-(10, 1)`).

Comment: That sounds pretty interesting! So first checking if those Segments intersect at all, than check if their endpoints are on different sides of each other segment..?

Comment: @philipp: if A and B are on different semiplanes in respect to the line CD and C/D are on different semi-planes in respect to the line AB then the two segments AB and CD have an intersection. The converse is also true (if they intersect then the endpoints of each segments are on different semiplanes in respect to the line of the other segment). If you need to just check if two segments intersect then there's no need to compute the intersection and you can use only multiplication/addition/subtraction. If you need the intersection point you also need division.

Answer (score 0):

### Line intercepts

The following functions finds the intercept, if any, as a point `{x, y}` of two lines defined by two points `{p1:{x,y}, p2{x,y}}` on each line.

The first two function are for line segments (each has a fixed length) and the last two functions are infinitely long lines.

#### Line segment intercept

As 4 points `p1 = {x,y}`, `p2 = {x,y}`, `p3 = {x,y}`, `p4 = {x,y}` defining end points of two line segments. Returns point only if there is an intercept, else return `undefined`.

```
function interceptSegs(p1, p2, p3, p4, p = {}) {
    const x1 = p2.x - p1.x, y1 = p2.y - p1.y;
    const x2 = p4.x - p3.x, y2 = p4.y - p3.y;
    const c = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
    if (c) {
        const x3 = p1.x - p3.x, y3 = p1.y - p3.y;
        const u = (x1 * y3 - y1 * x3) / c;
        if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
            const u = (x2 * y3 - y2 * x3) / c;
            if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
                p.x = p1.x + x1 * u;
                p.y = p1.y + y1 * u;    
                return p;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OR** As two lines `l1 = {p1:{x,y}, p2{x,y}}`, `l2 = {p1:{x,y}, p2{x,y}}` returns point only if there is an intercept.

```
function interceptSegs(l1, l2) {
    const a = {x: l1.p2.x - l1.p1.x, y: l1.p2.y - l1.p1.y};
    const b = {x: l2.p2.x - l2.p1.x, y: l2.p2.y - l2.p1.y};
    const c = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
    if (c) {
        const e = {x: l1.p1.x - l2.p1.x, y: l1.p1.y - l2.p1.y};
        const u = (a.x * e.y - a.y * e.x) / c;
        if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
            const u = (b.x * e.y - b.y * e.x) / c;
            if (u >= 0 && u <= 1) {
                return {x: l1.p1.x + a.x * u, y: l1.p1.y + a.y * u};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Intercept lines

Similar to above functions but assumes lines are infinitely long. Will return a point or `undefined` if lines are parallel.

```
function intercept(p1, p2, p3, p4, p = {}) {
    const x1 = p2.x - p1.x, y1 = p2.y - p1.y;
    const x2 = p4.x - p3.x, y2 = p4.y - p3.y;
    const c = x1 * y2 - y1 * x2;
    if (c) {
        let u = (x1 * (p1.y - p3.y) - y1 * (p1.x - p3.x)) / c;
        p.x = p3.x + x2 * u;
        p.y = p3.y + y2 * u;    
        return p;
    }
}
```

**OR** As lines `l1`, `l2` returns point only if there is an intercept. Returns `undefined` if line are parallel.

```
function interceptLines(l1, l2) {
    const a = {x: l1.p2.x - l1.p1.x, y: l1.p2.y - l1.p1.y};
    const b = {x: l2.p2.x - l2.p1.x, y: l2.p2.y - l2.p1.y};
    const c = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
    if (c) {
        const u = (a.x * (l1.p1.y - l2.p1.y) - a.y * (l1.p1.x - l2.p1.x)) / c;
        return {x: l2.p1.x + b.x * u, y: l2.p1.y + b.y * u};
    }
}
```